# "The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'http'" Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, ntlm, spring-3

I am trying to configure NTLM authentication, but receive error:

> cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no
> declaration can be found for element 'http'.

I read a lot of topics with a similar error, but I could not find a solution to my problem.

My security.xml file that causes an error is:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd" >
    
    <http access-denied-page="forms/error403.jsp" entry-point-ref="ntlmEntryPoint" servlet-api-provision="false"> 
        <intercept-url pattern="forms/error403.jsp" filters="none"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="forms/**" access="ROLE_GUEST,ROLE_OPERATOR,ROLE_ADMIN" />
                <custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>
    </http>
    
    <authentication-manager alias="mainAuthenticationManager"/>  
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref='userDetailsService' />

    <beans:bean id="userDetailsService"
        class="service.UserInfoService">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="usersByUsernameQuery" value="select distinct name, ' ' as password, 1 as enabled from TMP_SPRING_USERS where name=?" />
        <beans:property name="authoritiesByUsernameQuery" value="select name, role from TMP_SPRING_USERS where name=?" />
    </beans:bean>
      
    <beans:bean id="ntlmEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.ui.ntlm.NtlmProcessingFilterEntryPoint">
        <beans:property name="authenticationFailureUrl" value="forms/error403.html" />
    </beans:bean>
        
    <beans:bean id="exceptionTranslationFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter">
        <beans:property name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="ntlmEntryPoint" />
    </beans:bean>
    
    <beans:bean id="ntlmFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.ui.ntlm.NtlmProcessingFilter">
        <custom-filter position="NTLM_FILTER" />
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="mainAuthenticationManager" />
        <beans:property name="retryOnAuthFailure" value="true" />
        <beans:property name="stripDomain" value="true"/>
        <beans:property name="domainController" value="company.com" />
        <beans:property name="jcifsProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="jcifs.smb.lmCompatibility">0</beans:prop> 
                <beans:prop key="jcifs.smb.client.useExtendedSecurity">false</beans:prop> 
                <beans:prop key="jcifs.smb.client.domain">COMPANY</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="jcifs.smb.client.username">somenycuser</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="jcifs.smb.client.password">AReallyLoooongRandomPassword</beans:prop>
            </beans:props> 
        </beans:property> 
    </beans:bean>
    
  
</beans:beans>
```

Because as of version 3.X Spring Security doesn't include the NTLM extension anymore, I use it from http://aloiscochard.blogspot.com/2010/03/spring-security-ntlm-3.html article.

Please help me.

Comment: If this happens for you on Spring Security 5.2 or above, double-check that your `schemaLocation` points to the HTTPS URL (`https://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd`) - took me a good half an hour to figure out why my old `http://` URL was no longer working

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem solved, I forgot to add spring-security-config.jar. Also I changed some settings. The right security.xml is::

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.4.xsd" >

    <http access-denied-page="forms/error403.jsp" entry-point-ref="ntlmEntryPoint" servlet-api-provision="false"> 
                <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_GUEST,ROLE_OPERATOR,ROLE_ADMIN" />
                <custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="ntlmFilter"/>
        </http>

    <authentication-manager alias="mainAuthenticationManager">  
            <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService" />
        </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="userDetailsService"
        class="service.UserInfoService">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="usersByUsernameQuery" value="select distinct name, ' ' as password, 1 as enabled from TMP_SPRING_USERS where name=?" />
        <beans:property name="authoritiesByUsernameQuery" value="select name, role from TMP_SPRING_USERS where name=?" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="ntlmEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.ui.ntlm.NtlmAuthenticationFilterEntryPoint">
        <beans:property name="authenticationFailureUrl" value="forms/error403.html" />
    </beans:bean>



    <beans:bean id="ntlmFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.ui.ntlm.NtlmAuthenticationFilter">
                <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="mainAuthenticationManager" />
        <beans:property name="retryOnAuthFailure" value="true" />
        <beans:property name="stripDomain" value="true"/>
        <beans:property name="domainController" value="company.com" />
        <beans:property name="jcifsProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="jcifs.smb.lmCompatibility">0</beans:prop> 
                <beans:prop key="jcifs.smb.client.useExtendedSecurity">false</beans:prop> 
                <beans:prop key="jcifs.smb.client.domain">COMPANY</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="jcifs.smb.client.username">somenycuser</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="jcifs.smb.client.password">AReallyLoooongRandomPassword</beans:prop>
            </beans:props> 
        </beans:property> 
    </beans:bean>


</beans:beans>
```