# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'http'

Tags: spring, spring-security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'http'” Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561579/the-matching-wildcard-is-strict-but-no-declaration-can-be-found-for-element-h)

I am trying to integrate my application with spring security.
I have added my applicationContext-security.xml file in my apllication. but at the time of running, I am getting the below error:

```
2012-08-23 17:24:32,626 ERROR main [ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext] - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 32 in XML document from class path resource [cm-application-context-security.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'http'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:404)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:92)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:422)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:352)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:543)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1220)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:513)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:447)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:115)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:543)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:421)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1035)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:783)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:275)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'http'.
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:267)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:201)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
    ... 31 more
Starting Jetty on port 8888
   [WARN] Failed startup of context com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload@dc6a77{/,D:\Project\IBMP\IBMP_Release17\CM_UI_WORK\cm-ui_work\war}
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 32 in XML document from class path resource [cm-application-context-security.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'http'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:404)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:92)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:422)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:352)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:543)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1220)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:513)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:447)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:115)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:543)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:421)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1035)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:783)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:275)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'http'.
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:267)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:201)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
    ... 31 more
   [WARN] Nested in org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 32 in XML document from class path resource [cm-application-context-security.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'http'.:
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'http'.
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:267)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:201)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:92)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:422)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:352)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:543)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1220)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:513)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:447)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:115)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:543)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:421)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1035)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:783)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:275)
```

I dont know why this errors are coming. previously my application was using spring 2.5.6 distribution jars. but for spring security implementation I have added 2 extra jars.
i.e.
spring-security-core-3.0.2
spring-security-web-3.0.2

Below is my **applicationContext-security.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- - Sample namespace-based configuration - -->

<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">
    </global-method-security>  -->

    <!-- <beans:import resource="urm.xml" />  -->

    <beans:bean id="customAuthenticationProcessingFilter"
        class="com.onmobile.campaignmanager.urm.authentication.CustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter">
        <beans:property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/j_spring_security_filter" />
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="customUserDetailsService"
        class="com.onmobile.campaignmanager.urm.authentication.CustomUserDetailsService">
        <beans:property name="urmService" ref="urmService" />
    </beans:bean>

    <http use-expressions="true">
        <form-login login-page="/login.jsp" default-target-url="/Campaignmanager.html"
            authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?login_error=1"
            always-use-default-target="true" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp*" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/ForgetPassword*" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/cm-ui/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/gwt/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**/*.html" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <!--intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" /-->
        <logout logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"
            invalidate-session="true" />
        <remember-me />
        <session-management invalid-session-url="/login.jsp?loggedout=true">
            <concurrency-control max-sessions="1"
                error-if-maximum-exceeded="false" />
        </session-management>
        <anonymous enabled='false'/>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService" />
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

before I was getting the same kind of error for  tag also. after that as you can see above I have commented that one.

Please provide me any suggestion where to look if any body has faced or has any knowledge for the same issue.

Comment: Please do a search before posting. You will find the exact same question has been asked and answered many times before. For example, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561579/the-matching-wildcard-is-strict-but-no-declaration-can-be-found-for-element-h) is an exact duplicate.

Comment: @LukeTaylor: Sorry, I am new to this forum and thanks for your advice, I will keep this in mind :)

Answer (score 0):

You've probably forgotten to add `spring-secuirty-config.jar` to your classpath. (And use of Maven highly recommended because it takes care of dependencies.)

Comment: Hi All,<br/> I got my problem resolved. As I have told that my existing application were using spring 2.5.6 so as soon as I used spring security 3.0.3 it was throwing several errors, after that I added some new jars.<br/> spring-security-core-2.0.4.jar, spring-security-taglibs-2.0.4.jar, spring-security-core-tiger-2.0.4.jar, spring-security-acl-2.0.4.jar, spring-security-resin-2.0.4.jar, aspectjrt.jar, aspectjweaver.jar  <br/><br/> and also modified some of the configuration in my spring-security-context.xml <br /> <br /> Thanks you guys for your support.

Comment: I did not found any separate spring-secuirty-config.jar for spring-security 2.0.4

Comment: So why did you change the version? In question you wrote you had chosen 3.0.2, then here you wrote 2.0.4 - they are incompatible with each other and having both in classpath will get you in trouble. I also checked [the requirements](springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq.html#faq-requirements) - Security needs Spring in at least version 3 so either upgrade Spring to >= 3 or downgrade Spring Security to 2.0.7.