# Spring Security Error: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'http'

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, spring-security

I am working on a Google App Engine and I am trying to integrate Spring Security to the project, but I keep getting the below as soon as I run the Google App Engine application:

```
15-Jul-2013 13:09:13 com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: Nested in
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 16 in   XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml] is invalid;     nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The 
matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'http'.:
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'http'.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:131)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:384)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:318)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:423)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3188)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1933)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:711)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:400)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2756)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:647)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:232)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:284)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:522)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:436)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:249)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:307)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticServerInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticServerInstanceHolder.java:26)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractServer.startup(AbstractServer.java:80)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Servers.startup(Servers.java:82)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:237)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:339)
at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.<init>(DevAppServerMain.java:274)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:250)
```

This is how my spring-security.xml file looks like

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp.security" />

<beans:bean id="customAuthenticationProvider"
    class="com.myapp.security.CustomAuthenticationProvider"></beans:bean>

<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/"
        authentication-failure-url="/loginfailure" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

I have added spring-security-core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar in classpath as well. I am unable to resolve this error. I would really appreciate the help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of ["The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'http'" Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561579/the-matching-wildcard-is-strict-but-no-declaration-can-be-found-for-element-h)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that `spring-security-config-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar` is in your classpath too.

Comment: I have added the mentioned jar file in class path..but still its giving me the same error

Comment: This solution doesn't work for the present-day latest version, 5.0.7.RELEASE: 

`Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'global-method-security'.`

Comment: For me the issue was that xsd urls were http, when changed to https, it started working. E.g. ```http://www.springframework.org/schema/security https://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd```

Answer (score 2):

Adding @Johannes Tuikkala's  comment as a separate answer. So that it gets better visibility.

For me the issue was that xsd urls were http, when changed to https, it started working. E.g. `http://www.springframework.org/schema/security https://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd`

Comment: This is, most likely, because XML parsers by default will fetch the XSDs specified in xsi:schemaLocation from an external URL, and therefore block and need external Internet access whenever reading such XML. That's UNLESS a library provides a (hard-coded) mapping to a XSD resource contained in its JAR. Serious libraries like Spring do do this - but sometimes get it wrong... More background in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FINERACT-1180