# How to add http session-management tag in application context in Spring?

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven

I want to manage user sessions and forbid one user to login twice using the same credentials.

According to [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-concurrent-sessions) I've added the listener entry in my `web.xml` and tried to edit `context.xml`

My `context.xml` file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    <annotation-driven />
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.xyz.abc" />
</beans:beans>
```

and when I add lines from documentation:

```
<http>
    <session-management>
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
    </session-management>
</http>
```

below/under I got an error:
`The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.` Which means I can only have one root element. So I've added that code inside `<beans:beans>` and then another problem occured:

`cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'http'.` and `Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [http]`

For first error I tried the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561579/the-matching-wildcard-is-strict-but-no-declaration-can-be-found-for-element-h) and added:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

to my `pom.xml` to download the mentioned `spring-security-config.jar` and also added:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.3.xsd
```

to `xsi:schemaLocation` but nothing has changed.

From what I've found, the second error is connected with the first one.

**Edit:**

I followed @rmlan's lead and added: `xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"` and changed `<http>` to `<sec:http>`

And also added missing dependency to `pom.xml` :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

and another error popped up:

```
No AuthenticationEntryPoint could be established. Please make sure you have a login mechanism configured through the namespace (such as form-login) or specify a custom AuthenticationEntryPoint with the 'entry-point-ref' attribute
```

But it'll be handled in the future.

Comment: Your second issue is a new issue. You should accept the answer to your original issue and open a new question if you are still having problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is looking for the `http` tag in your default namespace, which is `http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc`

Either change your default namespace to `http://www.springframework.org/schema/security`, or declare that namespace with a prefix, and prefix your `http` tags with it.

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.3.xsd">
  <sec:http>
    <sec:session-management>
        <sec:concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
    </sec:session-management>
  </sec:http>
</beans:beans>
```